# Android LinearLayout overlapping imageView

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I am trying to use a cardview to have an imageview and to the right of it a linearlayout, the problem i am having is the linearlayout is getting drawn on top of my imageview.

I am using a listview to get items and display each item on the menu.

The blue square is my linearlayout, the image is the highlighted part
[image: The blue square is my linearlayout, the image is the highlighted part]

axml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listitemshadow"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuItemImageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picking" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menuItemNameTextView" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: don't use card view as main layout, always use another layout inside `cardview` because `cardview` works as frame layout, the whole thing put under another layout and that layout should under `cardview` .

Comment: Because parent is `CardView` and `CardView` allows overlapping. Put your `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` in either in `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation and set `weights` to `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` or in `RelativeLayout` and use inside `LinearLayout` attribute `toRightOf` and provide `id` of `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RelativeLayout` otherwise you will have to use too many layouts that are bad for performance. And also don't use `cardView` as a parent because it will overlap the elements. Use it inside a `RelativeLayout` or a `constraintLayout.`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listitemshadow"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/picking" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/menuItemImageView">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use card view as the main layout, always use another layout inside `cardview` because cardview works as frame layout, the whole thing put under another layout and that layout should under `cardview`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:padding="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuItemImageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuItemImageView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your linearlayout and image in another horizontal linearlayout instead of putting them directly inside cardview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listitemshadow"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menuItemImageView"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/picking" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/menuItemNameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:gravity="left" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionTextView"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/menuItemNameTextView" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the card view, use a list view. 
After that, make a custom layout for the list item i.e, make an XML file for the list item layout. After that create a custom adapter for adapting the list item to the list layout in the card view.
You can take the reference from this video:-
https://youtu.be/A-_hKWMA7mk